# How to solve Inaccurate battery status after removing battery

Tags: battery-life, battery-history

My phone battery is just about 2 months old. It can last for many days without browsing and over 12hours  streaming HD videos on YouTube. But something is strange. Any time I remove the battery ( high temperature or to switch SIM card or SD card ), phone doesn't care if battery was at 99%, on reboot, I realized battery has drastically reduce down to even 5%. At times I would remove the battery again and wait for some minutes (about 30)  and reboot again getting up to 40%.
What's the problem and how to solve it

Device : MTN Smart L 860 on Marshmallow 6.0

Comment: I had read of this happening long back. Reason given was that reboot causes a sudden load on the device and the battery drops but if you keep the device running for a while it fixes itself. Not having experienced it, I can't say with confidence

Comment: Mine doesn't fix with the device running for a while. Rather it seems to adjust itself if the device is left alone without a battery for hours. If I allow the device to keep on running with the faulty battery status, it would work as normal and soon battery low and then shutdown. When put on charge it would charge as normal

Comment: That's an another way I suppose. I now recall another way was to let it run and when it is close to low percentage charge it. But coming to your question, I would risk saying that it is poor OS management of battery level

Comment: Actually it wasn't like that before.

Comment: MTN smart L860  6.0